# "Группа Смерти"

Tags: орфография, этимология, идиоматика

Возник околофутбольный вопрос.

Есть такое понятие, употребляемое болельщиками и спортивными журналистами: **Группа смерти**. Обозначает трудную для выхода группу в соревнованиях с групповым этапом.

Нужно.

~1. Уточнить, является это сочетание идиомой или чем иным, и дать ему более или менее содержательное, но формализуемое определение.  
~2. Определиться с написанием - необходимость заглавных и кавычек. 
~3. Восстановить историю его появления - желательно с указанием источников.

*Помимо прочих нужд я задумал отредактировать статью в Википедии, но не располагаю ничем, кроме собственного субъективного мнения и уже дырявой памяти, поэтому нужна помощь.*

(+)
По третьему пункту нашел подробный комментарий в английской Вики, но не исключаю, что кто-то сможет что-то добавить.

Comment: Как сейчас помню, группой смерти была предварительная группа ЧЕ-1996, в которую входили сб. Германии (будущий чемпион Европы-96), сб. Чехии (будущий финалист ЧЕ-96), сб. Италии (серебряый призер ЧМ-1994) и сб. России. Италия с Россией "умерли", а немцы с чехами разыграли финал в итоге. Если бы наши выиграли у Чехии вместо ничьей 3:3, то вроде как проходили дальше. Давно дело было...

Comment: Это как первое появление?
Да ну, бросьте. 1970 г. Мексика. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_death

Comment: Я не сказал - первое. Просто пример.

Answer (score 1):

А. ВАРИАНТЫ ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ (их несколько)

1) ОБЩЕЕ определение: это такая группа

Группа смерти – группа в турнире (чемпионате, лиге), состоящая из примерно равных по высокому мастерству команд. Определяется при жеребьёвках.

2) Это термин для описания СИТУАЦИИ

Группа смерти — это неофициальный термин, используемый в футболе и других видах спорта для описания ситуации, которая часто возникает в ходе группового этапа турнира (как, например, первый раунд Чемпионата мира), где все команды в группе (или по крайней мере 3 из них) считаются примерно одинаковыми по мастерству.

3) Это самая непредсказуемая группа

Как правило в футболе "группой смерти" называют такую группу, в которую попали по жребию команды, занимающие лидерство в чемпионатах своих стран. Ключевым элементов является то, что любая из команд может квалифицироваться и любая может не выйти из группы. Другими словами, это самая непредсказуемая часть группового турнира.

4) Это группа смерти для слабой команды

Группа смерти - это высказывание применимое для более слабой команды, которая попала при жеребьевке в одну группу с более сильными командами и практически не имеет шансов выйти из группы.

ПРАВИЛЬНОЕ НАПИСАНИЕ

1) В специально литературе: группа смерти. Термин устоявшийся и всем понятный.

2) В остальных случаях: «группа смерти». Это также термин, в котором кавычки обозначают условность названия.

3) Нежелательно: 
а)  Группа смерти – это не имя собственное
Б) группа «смерти» -  условное значением имеет  не слово «смерти», а все словосочетание.

Comment: Примерно так.

Comment: Вариант без кавычек встречается очень часто в популярных спортивных изданиях или  колонках. Вряд ли можно считать его неправильным, можно отметить как разговорный. Что касается определений (все они цитаты из различных источников, футбольных словарей), то в статье можно привести все варианты, так как  они характеризуют термин с разных сторон (это и будет познавательно и интересно).

Comment: >Вариант без кавычек встречается очень часто в популярных спортивных изданиях или колонках  
  
Да, согласен. А вы называете эти здания "специальными"? Ну пусть так...